# I'm setting the site up for windows authentication in the web.config, but it's not being picked up by IIS

Tags: iis, web-config, windows-authentication, iis-8.5

On a windows server 2012r2 box with IIS 8.5, I have an plain html site with a web.config in it.

My config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Unfortunately, IIS doesn't seem to be picking up my Authentication Mode setting. I could make this work in IIS by setting the auth type to be windows, but that would involve me updating every server. Isn't there some way for IIS to pull the configuration from the web.config so that the value is set correctly on deployment? This seems to be the case for almost everything else dealing with IIS and the web.config, so I would venture to say that I'm not doing something right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently IIS doesn't really listen to the web.config unless you unlock the corresponding section in the application host config.

qBernardhttp://forums.iis.net/members/qbernard.aspx posted the answer here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1146296.aspx?How+to+set+authentication+with+appcmd+exe+or+ServerManager

(here's what he said for when the link might break)
For appcmd, you can set it via /section:xxxx. all auth schemes are locked except Form, so you either unlock it first or commit it at apphost level (meaning store the config in applicationHost.config, which is not so good as in xcopy deployment via web.config file.

Example.
appcmd set config "default web site" /section:windowsAuthentication /enabled:true /commit:apphost

or unlock first:
appcmd unlock config /section:windowsAuthentication
appcmd set config "default web site" /section:windowsAuthentication /enabled:true

Answer (score 0):

is your site a sub application?

try adding

```
<authorization>
 <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

or

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```